# What's the best measure of how much a value changes?

Tags: pre-post-comparison

From a car, I get a value every second for accelerator pedal, from 0 to 100%. When you don't touch it, it reports 0%, and when you kick it to the max, that is 100%.

I want to calculate how much change there is in this value. It will be one of many  indicators of how you drive (how aggressively).

The best I have so far, is to calculate the average absolute value of the change from one reading to the next.

I am sure statistics offer something better, but I don't know what.

My reasoning is that variance is not relevant. What I want is more like the total work you do on the pedal divided by how long the trip is.

---

When posting this, I have to specify tags. When writing "change", autofill suggest "change scores". Is that something I should look into?

Comment: I doubt the literature on "change scores" will be of much direct value for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Average absolute value from one reading to the next is potentially a very good measure of volatility.  You might consider whether a 1 second interval is optimal, vs. computing successive changes after averaging over, say, 3s intervals.  Other useful summaries might include the maximum acceleration over a long time period, and the 0.9 quantile of the 0-100 acceleration measurements.  But it would be nice to have data on break usage, depending on what your real unstated goal is.

Comment: "Acceleration" is ambiguous here!  When the pedal is at a constant *unchanging* setting, the *car's own acceleration* can be *zero*.  The rate of change of the pedal involves the third derivative of the car's position (mediated by the response of the drive train, of course), aka the [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)), and the *acceleration* of the pedal's position involves the fourth derivative of the car's position, aka the [jounce or snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce). Arguably, *positive acceleration of the pedal* is most closely related to aggressiveness.

Answer (score 1):

There are two analogous areas in which you may be able to find pre-existing formulae.

Water level measurements over time: it seems you are truly seeking a measurement similar to the most common water level over a given time period. Farming and geological sites will have loads of equations related to that for you to convert easily.

The second one is network bandwidth billing. A common billing measure is to take the 90th %ile of of average usage as the billable amount. This allows for the exclusion of brief spikes throughout a given time period.

Asking the web about water levels over time, or bandwidth utilization measurements should yield you a lot of substantial results.